# What game is this wooden die from?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image: a glossy wooden die with a black Star and blue and green circles on different sides]

[image: a glossy wooden die with a black Star and blue and orange circles on different sides]

What game, possibly a children's board game, is this die from or used to play?

Comment: Looks like a Haba component. What are the dimensions?

Comment: What is on the other sides of the die?

Answer (score 3):

This looks a lot like a dice from the game [Tipsy Tower](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/10687/tipsy-tower), specifically the Dutch version called 'Toren van Pisa'.

The goal of the game is to add pawns to the tower without it toppling. The colour rolled marks the floor where your pawn has to be placed. The star is a wildcard.

[image]

Comment: No picture of the game shows a wild spot on the die. No description of the rules mentions a wild card. A video showing a play through of Pisa, the game in the photograph you posted, shows a die without a wild spot.

Comment: The version I have at home does have a wildcard on the dice, and (as far as I remember) always had it. I'll have to dig it out and check what the rules say: maybe the dice got replaced at some time.

Comment: Is the die in your version the same as that die? Sid Sackson's Bazaar has a similar die with a wild card, but the wild card is a five pointed star, not an eight pointed one.